# Can I use an OLS regression model with assumption violations for filling the missing data and prediction?

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, predictive-models, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

I am working on a multiple linear regression model  as ordinary least squares  (OLS)with several predictors and one response variable.
The data is for the counties for different years around 2200 values. The mode is used for filling the missing values and future predictions. The model worked with OLS validated with cross validation method. However, the model performance is low.
To find a way for improving the model and checking  the OLS model basics, I checked the liner regression assumptions and the problem is:
The residuals have non-normal distribution (near uniform distribution) and there is heteroskedasticity in the data which is clear from scale-location plot and tests. Moreover, there is also autocorrelation in the residuals and the REESET test shows that nonlinear relationship can improve my model.
Now the question is:

1. Can I use this model for the prediction in spite of the assumption violations (heteroskedasticity, autocorrelation and non-normality of the residuals)?
2. How can I check the prediction ability of the model if the answer to the first question answer is positive? As I think when the regression model basics are fulfilled how can we trust such a model?

Comment: What do you mean by *OLD* in the title? What do you mean by *bro* in the body?

Comment: You did not seem to use an initial modeling strategy that is based on sound statistical principles but instead opted for a simple model then were surprised that something went wrong.  Go back to the drawing board.  Study various models and strategies.  Choose a model that does not assume normal residuals (e.g., a semiparametric regression model) and allow for nonlinearity up front, living within your sample size limitation when deciding on the number of parameters in the model.  See [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms) for details.

Comment: You asked if you can do that. The answer is you can but I am not sure it means anything. Like @FrankHarrell says, do it the right way. Often, in my own work, if I get the model correctly, the residuals are normally distributed with small magnitude errors.

Comment: @Frank Harrell, Thank you for the response. It is a project already done with MLR and my task is to validate the model and if it is Okay, use it for the prediction. The sample size problem is in the response variable and I can not change it. I will check for the model that you mentioned. I read in some posts that when you use a model for prediction the MLR assumptions are not necessary. But I think as you mentioned from the beginning we should consider  these limitations .

Comment: @ Carl Thank you for the answer. As mentioned in the comment, the model was already ready and it is kind of model test that I am doing. Now do you think I should reject the model and do the model from beginning with a new method without these assumptions?

Comment: In terms of validation of the model the most important single thing to do is to estimate an overfitting-corrected smooth calibration curve to demonstrate absolute accuracy.

Comment: @FrankHarrell BTW, do you have a link for an established method for overfitting-corrected smooth calibration curve to demonstrate absolute accuracy? It seems like an obvious thing to do, but haven't seen one. Feri, short of a book length answer, it might be easier for you to post data and ask how to predict whatever you are actually asking about. What should be done is so data and fit target dependent that the answer might be very much different than commonly used modelling.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you *can* use it for prediction.  You can use anything for prediction. It just might not be optimal.

For prediction, heteroskedasticity is more of a clue for a possible better way to feature engineer.  The classic example in my mind is years of education and income.  That relationship is heteroskedastic and the 'optimal' way to deal with it is to convert the years into dummies based on degree like 12, 16, 18 etc.

If your goal is prediction then you should judge your model by it's accuracy and use these assumption checks to better inform your strategy but realize you can have a great performing model while breaking assumptions.

You check the accuracy by holding out a set of your data from the model and predict on that set and see what the accuracy is. You should always have a baseline to judge against and for me that baseline typically is a linear regression and I usually abandon it for stronger performing methods.

If the prediction accuracy isn't all that great then just use some splines or a boosted tree or something which is more robust to the issues in your data.

Comment: Converting an ordinal or continuous predictor into a categorical variable is seldom a good idea.

Comment: @FrankHarrell This was just a general example of where an assumption being violated can lead to insights towards a better performing model which may help OP think of some other ways to improve theirs.